# Python: fix invalid json string

Tags: python, json, format

I have bad formatted JSON in string like this:

```
"{var_1=100, var_2={\"Code\": 200, \"Headers\": {\"content-type\": \"text/html; charset=utf-8\"}}, var_3=0}"
```

And I need it to be formatted as proper JSON like this:

```
{
    "var_1": "100",
    "var_2": {
        "Code": "200",
        "Headers": {
            "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        }
    },
    "var_3": "0"
}
```

Is there a quick fix for this?
Maybe some third-party library for python?
Did someone encountered a similar problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Cheers :)

Comment: This is not "bad formatted json", this is _invalid_ json (IOW :  it's not json at all). And the best solution here is to fix the issue at the source (the code that produces this invalid json) - if possible, of course ;-)

Comment: I agree it's not json at all, but basically bad formatted json is also not json... :)

Comment: Well yes, the distinction is a bit pedantic indeed xD - but usually when we think about "formatting" we think about about presentation, not syntax. But anyway: the main point was that it's better to fix the cause than the result ;-)

Comment: Sure, agree with that but in my case I have no influence on the cause...
And yes, you have right that 'formatting' here can be misleading. I'll change the title - to be more coherent.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex with `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast

s = "{var_1=100, var_2={\"Code\": 200, \"Headers\": {\"content-type\": \"text/html; charset=utf-8\"}}, var_3=0}"
print(ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r"(\w+)=", r"'\1':", s)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'var_1': 100,
 'var_2': {'Code': 200,
           'Headers': {'content-type': "text/html; 'charset':utf-8"}},
 'var_3': 0}
```

Comment: The way I understand it, the OP asks for "proper JSON", not for printing a Python dict, so it should really be something like ` json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r"(\w+)=", r"'\1':", s)), indent=2)`

Comment: if the strings contain `=` this may change things that shouldn't be changed. Only a proper parsing can solve this in a general way.

Answer (score 0):

JSON documents need to have double quotes. You need to fix the data from it's source.